# Display image from internal stroage to image view

Tags: android

I have my images under the   folder myImageFactory in internal storage.Now i need to get the path of the folder and then asign it to imageviwer. I cannot do it by using getFilesDir() bez my images are not  inside files folder. Now how I can get the file path and assign to imageviwers setimageurl(). Is there any way I can convert "path" to Uri.I have attached my File explore structure link below.

```
      public class GalleryImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
         ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());        
         File path = cw.getDir("myImageFactory", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);           
         Uri[] picture={
             //How to get the path and store it here        
            };
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return picture.length;
            }
            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return position;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                ImageView i = new ImageView(context);
                i.setImageURI(uri+ "/myimage.png");
                i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(200, 200));
                i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtQnA.png

Answer (score 0):

Add file:/// before file path..

and make sure you have these permissions in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

or

```
  File file = new File ("yourpath");

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagview);

    imageView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(file));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use images in your android application you have to put all of them in to any one of your drawable folder which is inside 'res' folder(eg:- res/drawable-hdpi) folder.Then you can access them by this way:

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.myimage);
```

or

```
 String drawableName = "myimage";///provide the image's name alone excluding its extension
 imageView.setImageResource(getResId(drawableName));
```

And also while naming image file please follow java variable naming convention.

The other ways of doing it are
1.Using using 'assets' folder and AssetsManager
2.Using 'res/raw' folder.
For more info visit the following link

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html